# MOTD gets rewritten

Tags: centos, centos5

Every time I restart my server my motd banner gets rewritten.
What program (or startup script) is doing this, and how can I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically disable this and I cannot recall what does it off of the top of my head.  I believe that it is an init script, try running this to find it:

`find /etc -type f -exec egrep '(motd|issue)' {} \;`

Comment: You might want a `-H` on that `egrep`.

Comment: thanks for the tip..found the symblic link to motd. took that off.